# org.hibernate.type.SerializationException : Could not deserialize for AtomicLong field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an AtomicLong field in my class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
public class Movie implements Serializable{    
@Column(name = "movie_following_count")
private AtomicLong moviefollowingCount;
```

the counterpart field in the mysql table is `BIGINT(20)`

as far as the field `moviefollowingCount` is Long it works great. But as soon as I change it to AtomicLong it throws a SerializationException : could not deserialize.

How do I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hibernate might not know how to persist an AtomicLong fields. AFAIK there is a way to persist fields of custom types. The other question is: why do you need an AtomicLong?

Comment: +1 to Thomas: an entity is a non-thread-safe class, that is not supposed to be shared between threads. Why in hell do you have AtomicLong in an entity? Use a long.

Comment: Well the class has a field which is the count of people following a movie. The entity is movie. User & Movie have a ManyToMany relationship. 
Every time a user follows a movie the count gets incremented & updated in the db therefore I've made it AtomicLong as the count is shared amongst multiple users; just like facebook likes for a post.If you think my design is incorrect please advice.

Comment: If I make the field as Long how do I share it amongst several threads? Or do I just write a concurrent strategy for the object access & update to & fro from the db & just simply use the long variable? Please see my initial question for the background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554474/incrementing-a-shared-atomiclong-variable-persisting-to-the-database

Comment: I would go for the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/30156346/5646962. The problem with AtomicLong is that it does not scale: if the number of your users increases you might need a second front end server running your application. However AtomicLong is not shared between machines, so it will no longer work, whereas the solution mentioned above will still work.

Comment: @underdog the concurrency is handled by the database. Each thread will have its own instance of the entity, and the count will thus not be shared between threads. You need to understand how JPA and transactions work. AtomicLong is not needed.